# Gated check-ins in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

Where I currently work we are considering upgrading from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012. One feature that I quite like is Gated Check-ins, as this ensures that the branch you are developing in remains pristine in terms of there being no check-ins/changesets that cause the build to break  due to compilation errors or failed unit tests.

However in TFS 2010 many of the developers and I found this feature a bit cumbersome to use. One usability problem was in regards to the need to reconcile your workspace after the CI build has successfully validated that your check-in does not break the build. Another issue was if your changeset did break the build the developers did not find it intuitive to unshelve the broken changeset.

Has the Gated Check-In experience been improved in TFS 2012? The one improvement that I have found by researching on the Internet is the ability to queue up a number of check-ins prior to invoking a CI build. Apart from that I have not found any further information, especially in regards to the developer/user experience of this feature.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2012 does add [batch gated checkins](http://mattvsts.blogspot.it/2012/12/batched-gated-check-ins.html), but other than this I find the gated checkin user experience to be very similar other than this.

Comment: As I had thought. Thanks @jamesj.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed one important thing about Gated-checked-in which is while the Gated-checked-in is running and it may take some times you may add and modify your code which means you may need to shelve the current code and get from the shelve what break the build.

Also the reconcile makes sense because when you start the build by check-in the code  you don't know if your files will check-in or not and it may also contain new modification while the build running, so this features designed for all situations not only one situation.

Comment: I can see your point @M.Radwan, and it does make some sense. It's just that from a developer perspective it will take some adjusting to, especially in regards to reconciliation after a successful build. The developers in my work environment are used to code being committed into source control straight away, and naturally would not expect their changes to effectively be undone from their machines and to have to get latest source WITH their most recent check-in.